# CSS footer width issue

Tags: css, css-float

I'm currently working on [this site](http://natural.siteprogression.com/) and I want the footer to be 100% (width) of the screen but it has refused to respond no matter what I do. I've checked to see if the ID has a duplicate but I saw nothing. The CSS code is as shown below:

```
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #293D61;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your footer is a nested div inside #rack.  At 100%, your footer will only be as wide as your outer/parent div.  You need to move it out of the parent div and make it a sibling

Comment: Yes it is. And it's also inside #header. Perhaps you have some malformed HTML?

Comment: What made you see it as if it was inside was an error in the comment that killed the </div> Thanks because it was your suggestion that helped me find the fault.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way,

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #293D61;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check whether your footer is is in inside some other div...? if so then it will not be of full page length....**